# Reference request and prerequisites for understanding the Sphere Theorem and the Loop Theorem in 3-manifold theory

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, 3-manifolds

As part of my directed studies project, my advisor has suggested that I completely understand the proof of the [Sphere Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_theorem_(3-manifolds)) and the [Loop Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_theorem) in 3-manifold theory and explain it to him. I have done an introductory and advanced course in general topology, and introductory courses in algebraic topology (homotopy theory, fundamental groups and simplicial homology theory). I've also spent the past month studying surgery on 3-manifolds through Knot Theory and the proof of the Lickorish Twist Theorem and the Lickorish Wallace Theorem from Dale Rolfsen's book [Knots and Links](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/rolfsen.pdf).

My question is that what other prerequisites would I need to understand both of these theorems. Any other resources (lecture notes, video lectures etc.) that explain these two theorems in detail would also be appreciated. Rolfsen suggests John Stallings [book](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/stallings1.pdf) and [paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970146) for these two theorems.

Comment: Also posted on MSE https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4733233/116321

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just read the proofs and see what (if anything) you are missing? Sounds like you already have sufficient background.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek I tried reading it from the mentioned sources but I am encountering concepts like Poincare Duality and Universal Coefficient Theorem etc. that I am unfamiliar with so I have to repeatedly go back and look these up. My background in 3 manifold theory and differential topology is limited which I'm trying to fix by reading John Lee's intro to topological and smooth manifolds. I was hoping to find a reference which would be dedicated to these two theorems and self sufficient in terms of prerequisites.

Comment: The usual method of reading research papers is to pick up necessary background as you go. This is  normal. Don't let this discourage you.

Comment: Sounds like mostly you're missing material from a slightly more advanced algebraic topology course. You should be able to find that material nicely explained in Hatcher's Alegraic Topology or Munkres's Elements of Algebraic Topology. Of course you may need other things as well, but those will certainly cover Universal Coefficients and Poincare Duality.

Comment: Andrew Casson has written lecture notes proving the sphere, disk, annulus, and torus theorems using "PL minimal surface theory" (following Jaco and Rubinstein).  The notes can be found here: https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masgar/casson.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [Marc Lackenby’s webpage](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/lackenby/) you can find notes on 3-manifold topology (Michaelmas 1999). The proof of the loop theorem in Chapter 9 uses special hierarchies (instead of Papakyriakopoulos’ towers) following an approach of Johansson. The machinery of special hierarchies is maybe involved to set up, but it pays off to prove the loop theorem, topological rigidity of Haken 3-manifolds, and solving the word problem and homeomorphism problems.

There are many possible approaches to the loop and sphere theorems now available. Stallings [gave a proof of the sphere theorem](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/article?mr=415622) as a corollary of the loop theorem using his theory of ends of spaces and groups acting on trees. See also [Jaco-Rubinstein](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/article?mr=987273).  One may also deduce the loop theorem from the sphere theorem by doubling.

These theorems also follow as corollaries of the geometrization theorem. The proof of geometrization via Ricci flow makes use of minimal surface techniques that were developed originally by Meeks and Yau in the proof of the equivariant loop and sphere theorems (subsumed by the orbifold theorem).